# Excel 2003 - assign a custom/user-defined property to an individual cell?

Tags: vba, properties, excel-2003

Does the Excel cell object expose "custom" properties? I'd like a cell to have a "tag" which will be used in a VBA function, however, I don't want this "tag" to be visible to a user.

For example;

Cell A1 has the custom property/tag "Personal||Finance" attributed to it. This property should (possibly) only be accessible via VBA. I can then use this property in a procedure in order to know where in a database the value of the cell should be saved. I will set the property using a user-form.

I hope this makes sense. In Access, I use the Tag property for a control to do things via VBA. The principle would be broadly the same, only instead of a control, I need to tag a cell.

Thanks,
Phil.

Answer (score 0):

Names would be a nice simple solution.  They are accessible via the user.

However, if you really want to hide it from the end user, you could create a very hidden worksheet.  Then create a custom class to manage the creation,deletion of the 'tag' elements and cell information to build a nice lookup table for your database mapping. The user could not access the sheet unless by VBA. This adds more complexity, but is entirely hidden from the user, and slightly more flexible than the names approach.

Comment: Thanks. I like this solution - the only "weakness" for my requirements is that the user may move the cell contents (insert rows before/left/etc.) Is there a trappable event when a cell/worksheet is updated that would allow me to "track" the position of the cell(s)?

Comment: Yes, every sheet has an onchange event that fires where a change is made in a cell, not sure if it gives you enough info to track inserting cells.

Comment: In your lookup table, you could simply place a link to the source cell to get the value/reference.  As the source cell is moved, your link will move with it, but all your tag attributes will not.  Then you just need to handle the deletion of the source cell, which will return a #REF error value to the lookup table cell.  How you handle that is up to you.